# Opencart company vehicles

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I am using opencart 2.3.0.2 version. The company which will use the site has deifferent vehicles for delivery and wants to manage them in the admin panel, but I cant find any module for that. Can someone tell me if there is such a module for that ?

Comment: Have you tried searching on [OpenCart's Module Forum](https://forum.opencart.com/viewforum.php?f=184)? I am not sure SO is the place to ask this kind of question.

Comment: Sounds oddly specific, in that I wouldn't be surprised if no one had yet authored this sort of logistics plugin... there are some types of modules that everyone creates and recreates with a new twist, mostly born out of necessity. But if no one else has found it necessary, you might need to be the first if you want to see that sort of functionality

Comment: This kind of thing is generally not done by a shopping cart application.  He might want to look for something more purpose built.